# Socket.io Flask demo application slow via uwsgi but fast via python

Tags: python, sockets, flask, websocket, uwsgi

I'm getting in touch with websocket applications and installed the Flask socket.io example from https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO

When I'm calling

```
python app.py
```

I'm able to connect to the demo site and get a average ping/pong latency of around 50ms.

**This is nice so far.**

But when I'm calling the application via uwsgi the latency goes up to around 800ms!!!

This is how I call it via uwsgi:

```
uwsgi --http :5000 --wsgi-file app.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --callable app --enable-threads --vacuum
```

The website appears and the websocket connection is working but **it's really really slow.**

Any idea what could be the reason for this?